# Diameter computation in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I'm new to Python and igraph and I wish to simulate a targeted attack to a network. Specifically, given a directed graph G, I want to progressively delete vertices from G according to their in-degree.
My function takes as input a list (vertices_to_delete) of vertices to delete from G plus the graph G.
It creates a copy of G, deletes from G the vertices in vertices_to_delete and computes, on the new instance of G, the size of the WCC and the diameter of the new graph. Such a process is thus repeated for different instances of vertices_to_delete (thus at each iteration I re-compute the size of WCC and diameter).

I report my code below. The results I get for WCC are in line with my expectations while the values of D are quite weird (I would expect that D increases but no clear pattern emerges).
I've tried my code on a dataset extracted from Wikipedia (Wiki-Vote - https://snap.stanford.edu/data/wiki-Vote.html). I think I'm not using the correct function for computing the diameter and that this could depend on the fact that G is directed.

Thanks a lot for your kind help and thanks to the developers/contributors of igraph for this wonderful package!

```
def attack(graph, vertices_to_delete):
    gc = graph.copy()
    gc.delete_vertices(vertices_to_delete)
    largest_connected_component = gc.clusters(mode = WEAK).giant() 
    wcc_size=largest_connected_component.vcount()
    diameter = gc.diameter()
    return wcc_size, diameter
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code - `diameter()` calculates the directed diameter by default. If you want to ignore the edge directions while calculating the diameter, use `diameter(directed=False)`.